# Ruby on Rails responds "no route matches" for all routes while rack routes command shows them as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

#### Situation

I'm absolutly new to Ruby but somewhat experienced with Django, Node and other technologies.
I'm trying to run a legacy project from my employer on my local, which is actually running in production. The first thing I did is to dockerize it. The Puma server starts up well, it connects to the postgres DB, responses ok to the root 127.0.0.1:3000 with the Rails default welcome page. Even swagger shows the expected endpoints and even /rails/info/routes shows the routes perfectly. Also rake routes shows exactly the same:

```
user@local:~/path_to/project$ sudo docker compose exec app rake routes
                               Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action                                                                 api/v1/users#index
                                      POST   /api/users(.:format)                                                                     api/v1/users#create
                             api_user GET    /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                 api/v1/users#show
                                      PATCH  /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                 api/v1/users#update
                                      PUT    /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                 api/v1/users#update
                                      DELETE /api/users/:id(.:format)                                                                 api/v1/users#destroy
                       api_auth_login POST   /api/auth/login(.:format)                                                                api/v1/authentication#login
```

But when I make a request to, for example, /api/auth/login, it responds:

```
    {
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "exception": "#<ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches [POST] \"/api/auth/login\">",
    "traces": {
        "Application Trace": [],
        "Framework Trace": [
            {
                "exception_object_id": 47259696989680,
                "id": 0,
                "trace": "actionpack (6.0.3.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:36:in `call'"
            },
            {
                "exception_object_id": 47259696989680,
                "id": 1,
                "trace": "actionpack (6.0.3.7) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:33:in `call'"
            }, 
[...]
```

#### Controllers

```
├── controllers
│   ├── api
│   │   └── v1
│   │       ├── api_controller.rb
│   │       ├── authentication_controller.rb
│   │       ├── axes_controller.rb
│   │       ├── invites_controller.rb
│   │       ├── metrics_controller.rb
│   │       ├── organizations_controller.rb
│   │       └── users_controller.rb
│   └── application_controller.rb
```

#### authentication_controller.rb

```
module Api::V1
  class AuthenticationController < ApiController
    before_action :authorize_request, except: :login
    include AuthHelper
    def login
      @user = User.find_by(game_id: params[:game_id], email: params[:email])
      if @user&& @user.valid_password?(params[:password])
        render json: generateToken(@user), status: :ok
      else
        render json: { error: 'unauthorized' }, status: :unauthorized
      end
    end

    private

    def login_params
      params.permit(:email, :password, :game_id)
    end
   
  end
end
```

#### config/routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  mount Rswag::Ui::Engine => '/api-docs'
  mount Rswag::Api::Engine => '/api-docs'
  devise_for :users
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
  namespace :api do
    scope module: :v1, constraints: ApiVersion.new('v1') do

      resources :axes
      get '/metrics', to: 'metrics#get_metrics'
      get '/requests', to: 'organizations#requests'
      resources :organizations
      resources :invites
      resources :users do 
        post 'forgot_password', on: :collection
        post 'reset_password', on: :collection
        post 'google_auth', on: :collection
        get 'check_hash', on: :collection
        get 'export', on: :collection
      end
      post '/auth/login', to: 'authentication#login'
      post '/addmember', to: 'users#addUserOrganization'
      get '/*a', to: 'application#not_found'
    end
  end
end
```

I don't know what else to try. Please HELP!!

Comment: please show the call you are attempting to make.

Comment: you have constraints on api routes `ApiVersion.new('v1')` which have to match the request as well.

Comment: I'm trying to make a POST request to http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/auth/login . That's how it works on production. I've also tried .../api/v1/auth/login with the same results.

Comment: @Alex that was the problem, the constraint expected some custom header. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize about the constraint, now looking for ApiVersion class...

```
class ApiVersion
  attr_reader :version, :default

   def initialize(version, default = false)
    @version = version
    @default = default
  end

   # check whether version is specified or is default
  def matches?(request)
    check_headers(request.headers) || default
  end

   private

   def check_headers(headers)

    accept = headers[:accept]
    accept && accept.include?("application/vnd.some_string.#{version}+json")
  end
end
```

So adding the header

```
Accept: "application/vnd.some_string.v1+json"
```

did the trick.